# How to load Ui-component form data using another column instead of primary field Magento 2?

Tags: uicomponent, model, magento2.3.0, resource-model, ui-form

I have created a form using Ui-component it is working fine while adding new form & edit form.

But I would like to do customization as per my requirement. Default Magento Ui form data is display using primary field

```
 <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">tag_id</argument>
```

resource model. 
but I would like to load & display data with another column. is it possible to do this kind of customization? if yes then how can I do this? and is it a valid way?

**What i have tried :**

I changed

```
  <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">tag_id</argument>
```

primary field to another field in Ui-component form, but it's give **SQL** error because Ui-component called resource model and resource model load data based on primary field.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.